# Server 2008R2 consuming more memory

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am using this server for past few weeks and it is R0990 Dell with 4 intel xeon 7550 CPUs. All of a sudden all the processes started using more memory, even if I restart and reboot the server. Has anyone seen this issue ? How do I know if any system parameter changed, which caused this?

Comment: We need more information, what processes are using more memory, what changes have you made?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to know in Windows Server 2008 to see a log of System Related changes that were done. Problem is this server's administrator changed couple of times. So, there is no way to know what system's parameter that got changed.

-Brajesh

Comment: On tracking changes in Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/189024/version-control-for-windows-configuration/192873#192873